# Laravel: register 'locale' middleware

Tags: php, laravel, locale, middleware

I somehow made the mistake to register my `setLocale`-middleware to `protected $middlewareGroups` in the `Kernal.php` like this:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        ...,
        \App\Http\Middleware\setLocale::class,
    ],
];
```

but surprisingly this worked, so I thought I did it right.

I now noticed this (after I was looking for some tutorials about localization) and corrected it immediately, registered my middleware like this in Kernal.php :

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'locale' => \App\Http\Middleware\setLocale::class,
];
```

and added this to my `web.php` since I didn't have this before :

```
Route::middleware('locale')->group(function() {
    ...
});
```

My question now is, why did it work when I registered it to the `$middlewareGroups`?

Is this maybe just another way to register middleware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `web` middleware defined in the `$middlewareGroups` property, is applied by default for routes defined in `routes/web.php`.

This is done in the `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` file shipped by default with a fresh laravel project.

Side note: if you execute `php artisan route:list` in your project's root folder the output will show you all the various middlewares applied to the routes you have defined.

Comment: Which way would you recommend to do? It's really a small application having six routes.

Comment: I would define the middleware in the `$routeMiddleware` property, and then, if you need that middleware applied automatically to the routes defined in `web.php`, simply put `'locale'` in the `web` middleware group. This way you can still assign the locale middleware when needed for routes outside the web group